# What's the fastest way to travel the end in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

What's the fastest way to travel through the end in Minecraft? I need to get out SUPER far, and holding shift while placing blocks isn't cutting it. There has to be a mod out there that can help me achieve this. Flying is not an option.

Answer (score 5):

Speed potions will speed you up even when sneaking, you can use it to speed up the ordeal of placing 2000 odd blocks. You'll still go slower than if you were not holding shift, but it really helps.

Answer (score 1):

Smart Moving Mod, That really speeds you up in The End. I've tested it and it really works.

Comment: But does it work in smp?

Comment: Yes, It does work.

Comment: @Bailey Without also being installed on the server?

Comment: Yes! You need to install it on your minecraft client.

Comment: If you are using a mod, you can as well simply use `/tp` and port to where you want.

Answer (score 0):

If dying isn't a problem, you could concider launching your self out of a [TnT cannon](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Mechanisms#Cannons)

if the server has [RideTheDragon](http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/ridethadragon/) or a other ridable dragon Bukkit plugin/mod then you could use that aswell.

Answer (score -4):

/speed 100 is the fastest way to the end but you have to be on a serev for that soz

Comment: On a what for what now?